# Chaining promises Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have to call an API for an array of endpoints that I later use to fetch data from a second API.

```js
// Raise isLoadign flag
    this.$store.commit('isLoading', true);
    // Initial data fetch
    this.$store.dispatch('getAvailableProductGroups').then(() => {
      // Call API for every available product
      for(let group of this.$store.state.availableProductGroups) {
        // Check if it's the last API call
        this.$store.dispatch('getProductsData', group).then((response) => {
          // // Reset isLoading flag
          // this.$store.commit('isLoading', false);
          });
        }
    });
```

When I request the endpoints list from the first API I set up a isLoading flag, but I don't know how to check when the last promise has been resolved so that I can reset the flag.

Comment: Use `Promise.all`

Comment: @Bergi not directly linked to the question but should such code (nested action) be in some `actions.js` file? The `this.$store.dispatch` makes me think that this code is written within a template.

Comment: tried it but couldn't make it work. any code snippet that can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Raise isLoadign flag
this.$store.commit('isLoading', true);
// Initial data fetch
this.$store.dispatch('getAvailableProductGroups')
  .then(() => {
    // Call API for every available product
    return Promise.all(this.$store.state.availableProductGroups.map(group => {
      // Check if it's the last API call
      return this.$store.dispatch('getProductsData', group);
    });
  })
  .then((allResults) => {
    this.$store.commit('isLoading', false);
  });
```

But it **SHOULD** be in the store actions, not in vue-component.

Comment: I put it in the component because I dispatch the action when the component is mounted

Comment: you can add "isLoading" into vuex state and use Vuex.mapState on the Component to read (or watch it).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of promises with `.map()` and resolve with `.all()`

**Without async/await**

```
this.$store.commit('isLoading', true);
this.$store.dispatch('getAvailableProductGroups').then(() => {
    // Create an array of promises
    const groupPromises = this.$store.state.availableProductGroups.map(group =>  this.$store.dispatch('getProductsData', group))
    Promise.all(groupPromises).then( values => {
        // array of promise results
        console.log(values);
        this.$store.commit('isLoading', false);
    });
});
```

**With async/await**

```
async function doSomething() {
    try {
        this.$store.commit('isLoading', true);
        await this.$store.dispatch('getAvailableProductGroups')
        // Create an array of promises
        const groupPromises = this.$store.state.availableProductGroups.map(group =>  this.$store.dispatch('getProductsData', group))
        // Wait to resolve all promises
        const arrayOfValues = await Promise.all(groupPromises);
        this.$store.commit('isLoading', false);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```